# How to Integrate ASP.Net Webforms website with an ASP.Net MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, web, integration

How would I run both of them under one main website, say www.example.com, which is written and deployed using a Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC web application project, and where an ASP.Net Web Forms website, would run from a subdirectory of the main site, say www.example.com/myapp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Hanselman's [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).  The basic idea is that you add a regular WebForm to your MVC project, then tell the routing engine to ignore that path when doing MVC routing.