# Deploy ASP.NET website alongside ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I am working on an upgrade for a company website. It currently in production using vanilla ASP.NET. For the upgrade I switched the framework to ASP.NET MVC.

I am ready to deploy a beta version of the website. I have tested it locally by creating another website in IIS and just copying the published files there; that works. I only have access to the production web server through FTP. I tried copying those same files into a subdirectory on the root path, but it won't load the website.

How would I go about deploying the ASP.NET MVC project alongside the existing vanilla ASP.NET so that I can get to the beta site with just www.mycompany.com/beta?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Integrate ASP.Net Webforms website with an ASP.Net MVC web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519875/how-to-integrate-asp-net-webforms-website-with-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application)

Comment: No, that's not a duplicate. He just wants to run the MVC application in a sub folder.

Comment: @Manticore, right, thats integration, he can only access the site through FTP, not IIS, so he can't create a virtual directory.

Comment: @jfar so you're saying the right answer should be "you can't", and I shouldn't give him alternative ways like creating a sub domain?

Comment: @Manticore, I didn't say he couldn't, I linked to another question explaining exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to make the beta folder into a virtual directory so that it gets its own Application.

This has to be done through the IIS manager, and can't be done through FTP. In IIS 7.5 there is a menu option for converting a directory to an application ("Convert to Application") when right clicking on a directory. That would work great in this case.

I would suggest that you ask for a subdomain instead, e.g. beta.mycompany.com, that way it will have its own application to run in.

Comment: " only have access to the production web server through FTP"